# getResourceAsStream() returning null for properties file

Tags: java, resources, classloader

I try to load a file named `config.properties` in the package `config`.

[image: My project setup]

A snippet of my code in `Main.java`:

```
        //Read config.properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        System.out.println(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("config/config.properties").toString());
        InputStream propertiesFile = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/config.properties");
        properties.load(propertiesFile);
```

This however gives me a `NullPointerException`. But when I load `img/background/background.png` I use: (from `Panel.java`)

```
background = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("img/background/background.png")).getImage();
```

This works fine. I've read a lot of questions on stackoverflow already, but can't find a solution to my problem. I do not see the difference between the loading of the background image or the properties file, other than the fact that the properties file is loaded in a static context. But as far as I can see, this should work.

What am I forgetting?

**EDIT:** I just ran `System.out.println(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("config/config.properties").toString());`, which printed the correct path to `config.properties`.

**Stacktrace:** `java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.Main.startGame(Main.java:70)
    at main.gui.panel.MenuPanel$1.actionPerformed(MenuPanel.java:31)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)`

**`Main.java`** - line 70:

```
int maxFPS = Integer.getInteger(properties.getProperty("FPS"));
```

**`config.properties`**:

```
FPS=45
fpsCap=1
```

Comment: _different class than Main.java_ Which class?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'll update the picture and add it. On it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis See question again.

Comment: Mind posting the stacktrace? Also, show where you declare `properties`. `properties` could be null, and calling `properties.load` could be where the NPE is getting thrown

Comment: @VinceEmigh Done. On a side note: what is a stacktrace exactly?

Comment: Don't catch the exception, and the full stack trace should be printed automatically. Or catch it, and in the catch block, use `exception.printStackTrace()`

Comment: It's the error that shows up in your console as red; the one that you saw, which informed you that there was a NullPointerException.

Comment: You haven't done what I told you to do. This is the result of printing an array of StacktraceElement. Not the result of printStackTrace().

Comment: @VinceEmighExcuse me. Think I got it right this time.

Comment: Now tell us which line is line 70 of Main.java. That's where the exception is thrown, as indicated by the stack trace.

Comment: Did you try adding a '/' prior to the rest of the filename? "/config/config.properties"

Comment: @JBNizet Added line 70 and config.properties

Comment: @DanW Yes, didn't work either.

Comment: Side note: `Integer#getInteger(..)` is not the appropriate method to use. Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). You probably want `parseInt`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you for that side note. Appartently that was what was going wrong. Now when I print properties.getProperty("FPS") I get 45, so the inputstream wasn't the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't with the `getResourceAsStream("config/config.properties")`, but with the way I read the properties. Property `FPS` is written as a `String`, to make this in an `int` I had to use `Integer.parseInt()`, instead of `Integer.getInteger()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting it from the current thread context loader:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    try (InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream("config/config.properties")) {
        properties.load(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot start, properties not found.");
    }
```

This code compiles for JDK 7+, since it uses auto closeable, but can be translated to previous JDK version by moving the resource loader statement to be in in the try-catch clause.

Comment: You use `applicationProperties.load(in);`, shouldn't this be `properties.load(in);`?

Comment: Yeah you were right about the applicationProperties ->  properties load, already edit the code sample.

Comment: Added the config/ path to find your properties file to the sample code.